# Scraping a web page for .pdf link's and writing all of the matching links to a text file in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am an aspiring developer. As one of my projects, I am learning how to do web scraping. The goal is here to scrape a given webpage for any links that are PDFs and saving those links to a text file in NodeJS. With the given code, I am successfully console logging all of the matching links, but I am only getting one file written to my text file. Can someone steer me into the right direction?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs/promises");

let myNewURL =
  "https://www.renault.co.il/cars/Zoe/index.html?fbclid=IwAR1RtxbC_U2fImp9_KXJuQ869h5Wv77fyZVj8uBOU86rU90wb2L_NfrNppc";

async function scrapeSite(url) {
  console.log("firing");
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  //this gives back an actual array, not a node list
  const linkCollection = await page.$$eval("a", (links) => {
    return links.map((link) => {
      return link.href;
    });
  });

  for (const link of linkCollection) {
    if (link.includes(".pdf")) {
      console.log(link);
      await fs.writeFile("pdfLinks.txt", link);
    }
  }

  await browser.close();
}

scrapeSite(myNewURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.writeFile` overwrites the original file with each call. Try `fs.appendFile` instead. I've also added a newline (`\n`) at the end so the links are on individual lines:

```
for (const link of linkCollection) {
  if (link.includes(".pdf")) {
    console.log(link);
    await fs.appendFile("pdfLinks.txt", link + '\n');
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could collect the links into an array first, then write them all together:

```
const pdfLinks = [];

for (const link of linkCollection) {
  if (link.includes(".pdf")) {
    console.log(link);
    pdfLinks.push(link);
  }
}

const output = pdfLinks.join('\n')
await fs.writeFile("pdfLinks.txt", output);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Any idea how I'd separate them so they're not all one giant lump of text?

Comment: Concatenate `\n` or `\r\n` to the end to add a new line, depending on if you're on a *nix platform or on Windows :)

Comment: Amazing, thank you for this!  Will mark the answer as having solved my issue as soon as it lets me!

Comment: Glad I could help! I added another variant to introduce [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - it's super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

use append flag:

```
await fs.writeFile("pdfLinks.txt", link+'\n',{flag:'a'});
```